# Unit Testing an Angular Service using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular and TDD in angular

I want to test drive a service, but before that wanted to understand the flow. I am having a few issues. I keep getting this error

Firefox 47.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
  at C:/domain/domain/test/unitTest/spec/client/lib/angular.min.js:6

My app.js file is as follow

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'smart-table',
    'ngRoute',
    'ng-bs3-datepicker',
    'angucomplete-alt',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'checklist-model',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'ui.bootstrap'
    ])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

//some code here

}])
```

My services.js code is as follows

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('usersLocationService', function () {
    this.SetLocation = function (place) {
        var address = {};
        //some code here
        return address;
    };
}
```

My karma.conf.js  file is as follows

```
// Karma configuration


module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'test-main.js',

    'test/unitTest/spec/client/lib/angular.min.js',
    'test/unitTest/spec/client/lib/angular-mocks.js',
    'public/Controllers/**/*.js',
    'public/Controllers/subDomain/**/*.js',

    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js',
    'test/unitTest/spec/client/**/*.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Firefox'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
 })
}
```

And finally my unitTest case code is

```
"use strict";
describe('Test Suite for UserLocationService', function () {
beforeEach(angular.module.mock('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_usersLocationService_) {
    this.sut = _usersLocationService_;
}));


it('Should return the address from the google location place', function() {
    var place = {};
    var data = this.sut.SetLocation(place);
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [no `angular.module.mock` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module). It is

```
angular.mock.module('myApp')
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight :)